# Best way to use an excel template in a .NET application?

Tags: excel, vb.net, embedded-resource

I built a simple vb.NET Windows Application using Visual Studio, in which it collects data, opens an excel template and places the data on a worksheet before renaming and saving a copy of the file to a specified location.

My intention is to send this application to a few people to use, who are not connected by any network. I was thinking of having a text field which automatically assumes the newly created workbook will be saved to the user's documents directory and will allow the user to update this path if they wish before collecting any data.

For the template, I want a pretty robust method that ensures the template can be found. I will put a check for finding the template when the application initially runs, but it would be great if I could embed this template in the application, so that when I send the application to a new user, I only have to send one .exe application. Is this possible? The other method I was thinking was to have the template in the same directory as the application and instructing the user to ensure this is the case. The check that then searches for the template will allow the user to point to where the template actually is if it cannot find it in the same directory as the application.

At the moment, I open and rename the template using the following method

```
Dim newLocation As String = <I create a string for the new path and name>
fso.CopyFile(Source:=<Current template path>, Destination:=newLocation)
```

If embedding an excel workbook can be done I would love to know how (e.g. add an existing item, set the build action to 'Embedded Resource' and then...?) , or alternatively if placing the template in the same directory as the application is the most suitable option I would like to hear thoughts as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make vb.NET Windows Application using Visual Studio - use for such
application Excel. Just make Excel file with protected cells - in which you have to
write formulas and personal data for every user - which must stay unchangeable and cells for data, which user have to enter every time. This is more quick and easy